# NaN output when using reduce to add all elements in Array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reduce, array-algorithms

Solving a coding challenge to find the missing number given an array of positive numbers from 1 to n, such that all numbers from 1 to n are present except one.

I am using an approach to calculate the expectedSum using the Arithmetic Series Sum Function

Sum(1−n) = (n * (n + 1)) / 2)

​​and subtract the actual sum from it to get the missing number.

---

This works with my hard-coded addition function (commented out in code snippet) but not when I use the reduce method to accumulate the values in the array.

I get **NaN** when using the reduce method to get the actualSum:

Does anybody know why I'm getting Nan?

```
let findMissing = function(arr) {
  n = arr.length + 1; //exactly 1 number missing
  let expectedSum = Math.floor((n * (n + 1)) / 2);

  //   let actualSum = 0;
  //   for (let i in arr) {
  //     actualSum += arr[i];
  //   }
  const actualSum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  return expectedSum - actualSum;
};

console.log(findMissing([1, 2, 3, 5, 6]));
```

Comment: `actualSum` is a function, you are subtracting the function from something, not any return from it, never calling it...

Comment: btw, `n * (n + 1) / 2` returns for every integer `n` an integer result. no need to floor the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
const actualSum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

You are defining `actualSum` to be a function.

```
return expectedSum - actualSum;
```

A number minus a function is not a number (NaN). I think what you're trying to accomplish is:

```
return expectedSum - actualSum(arr);
```

Or, alternatively, don't make it a function but just reduce the array directly:

```
const actualSum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
return expectedSum - actualSum;
```